# What is the difference between drag coefficient and skin friction coefficient?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, friction, definition, flow, drag

I am trying to understand what caused drag. For example when fluid is passing a plate, if the fluid is still laminar at the end of plate, the drag coefficient could be evaluated as twice friction coefficient. But in my understanding, isn't drag caused entirely by friction?[image]

Comment: Drag coefficient is the integral of friction coefficient (if I understand the terms you're using correctly). You might want to have a look at this post: https://engineering.stackexchange.com/a/29620/21383.

Comment: @IvanNepomnyashchikh Hi! Thank you so much for your reply! I didn't realize that 2 is coming from integral!